# Node getting confused between same names static files present in different folder

Tags: node.js, angular, web, routes

I have the following code in my app.js file,

```
   app.use(express.static('views/app1/dist'));
   app.use(express.static('views/app2/dist'));
```

but here I have same named JS files in both folder, they are designed to represent respective HTML file present in the same folder.
The problem here is that even though I am routing to "app2" HTML file, the "app1" JS files are getting called.
Need help in making NODE understand which folder files to execute.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code screams that you are using NODE.JS with EXPRESS, and Angular 4, so following are the tips for you:

1. Avoid having files with the same name, it increases the computation load on the server,
2. Instead of using `ng build`, use `ng build --prod`, this will create unique named files, so no clashing.